# No Data on Get Api, What I'm Doing Wrong in this

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm learning API with Node & Express. But getting this error. Don't know how to check or debug this. Anyone can please explain this to me. Im not getting any data. and getting 404 error. tried everything but nothing helps me out . Also someone please mentioned some good tutorial for building an API with Node.js with Express with any database as I want to learn API.

**Router.js**

```
const { Product } = require('../schema/Product')
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const productList = await Product.find();
        if (!productList) {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err, success: false })
        }
        res.send(productList);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await console.info('Job Done');
    }
})
module.exports = router;
```

**Model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    image: {type:String},
    countInStock: {type:Number},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

require('dotenv/config');

const api = process.env.API_URL
const morgan = require('morgan');
const ProductRouter = require('./routes/product-routes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Router
app.use(`${api}/products`, ProductRouter);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

const port = 2100;

mongoose.connect(process.env.CON_STRING)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection is Ready")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });

app.listen(port, () => {
    // console.log(api)
    console.log(`Server started on Port http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Please make sure that the API endpoint is correct. And make sure your GET request to http://localhost:2100/api/products (assuming api is the base API_URL defined in your .env file). Can you share them again?

Comment: Here are some resources you can refer to:
Express.js official documentation: https://expressjs.com/
Node.js API Development for Beginners (YouTube tutorial series): https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jBcybHMTIia56aV21o2cZ8
Build a RESTful API Using Node.js and Express (FreeCodeCamp article): https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-restful-api-node-js-express-js/
Building a RESTful API with Node and Express (DigitalOcean tutorial): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js

Comment: @louis API_URL = /api/eCom is this

Comment: 1) localhost:2100/api/eCom/products is your endpoint which has 404 error?
2) this is basic question. do you have the code fetching products inside product-routes.js file or router.js file? As I look you have the code inside router.js file, which one?